# extract attribute from each row in an html table

Tags: javascript, html, extract

I have the following table in HTML, and would like to programmatically extract the call_id attribute from each row in the table.

I am inserting both the code and a simplified view from my editor, so you can see what I am interested in:

Simplified view:
[image]

I do the following call to get the entire table, and would then like to use this object to retrieve the data from:

```html
var recordingTable = parent.recordingsFrame.document.getElementById("recordingTable");
```

For this solution I am aiming for pure javascript, and not use the help of an external library.

```html
<table cellspacing="1" id="recordingTable"><input id="" name="" type="hidden" value="recordingTable">
    <thead class="callView">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <translate>STATE</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate>Call ID</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate>Text Type</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate>Start time</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate>Call duration</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate>Radio/Unit ID</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate>Participant name</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate>Tag</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate>Note</translate>
            </th>
            <th>
                <translate></translate>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="callView">
        <tr active="0" archivecount="0" callprovidertype="16" call_id="5" callsempty="false" deleted="false" flags="1" haslink="false" onlinecount="1" screenreccount="0" screensempty="true" issms="false" istext="true" style="background-color: rgb(208, 230, 248);">
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);">
                <div id="pics_scrollPanel">
                    <table cellspacing="0" id="pics"><input id="" name="" type="hidden" value="pics">
                        <thead></thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o iTags" id="smsCallIcon" title="message"></i></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><span class="icon-dvd-archive-restored spanTags" id="restoredCallIcon" title="restored"></span></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);"><span>5</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);"><span>2013-08-06 19:11:24</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);"><span>00:02:00</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);">
                <div>
                    <div>5010</div>
                    <div>5010 (Caller)</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);">
                <div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);">
                <div title="00 D4 14 86 7E CA 3B 7D 61 20">00 D4 14 8...</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tableColumn" style="color: rgb(18, 159, 221);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr active="0" archivecount="0" callprovidertype="16" call_id="4" callsempty="false" deleted="false" flags="1" haslink="false" onlinecount="2" screenreccount="0" screensempty="true" issms="false" istext="true">
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div id="pics_scrollPanel">
                    <table cellspacing="0" id="pics"><input id="" name="" type="hidden" value="pics">
                        <thead></thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o iTags" id="smsCallIcon" title="message"></i></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><span class="icon-dvd-archive-restored spanTags" id="restoredCallIcon" title="restored"></span></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>4</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>2013-08-06 19:11:17</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>00:02:00</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div>
                    <div>8882103</div>
                    <div>5006 (Caller)</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div title="00 D4 0E 96 7E DF 9E FC 80 F0">00 D4 0E 9...</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tableColumn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr active="0" archivecount="0" callprovidertype="16" call_id="3" callsempty="false" deleted="false" flags="1" haslink="false" onlinecount="1" screenreccount="0" screensempty="true" issms="false" istext="true">
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div id="pics_scrollPanel">
                    <table cellspacing="0" id="pics"><input id="" name="" type="hidden" value="pics">
                        <thead></thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o iTags" id="smsCallIcon" title="message"></i></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><span class="icon-dvd-archive-restored spanTags" id="restoredCallIcon" title="restored"></span></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>3</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>2013-08-06 19:11:11</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>00:02:00</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div>
                    <div>5010</div>
                    <div>5010 (Caller)</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div title="00 D3 F1 16 7E 3D D5 87 80 60">00 D3 F1 1...</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tableColumn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr active="0" archivecount="0" callprovidertype="16" call_id="2" callsempty="false" deleted="false" flags="1" haslink="false" onlinecount="1" screenreccount="0" screensempty="true" issms="false" istext="true">
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div id="pics_scrollPanel">
                    <table cellspacing="0" id="pics"><input id="" name="" type="hidden" value="pics">
                        <thead></thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o iTags" id="smsCallIcon" title="message"></i></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><span class="icon-dvd-archive-restored spanTags" id="restoredCallIcon" title="restored"></span></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>2</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>2013-08-06 19:08:47</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>00:02:00</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div>
                    <div>8882107</div>
                    <div>5014 (Caller)</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div title="20 D4 12 BE 7E 93 E9 4C E1 20">20 D4 12 B...</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tableColumn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr active="0" archivecount="0" callprovidertype="16" call_id="1" callsempty="false" deleted="false" flags="1" haslink="false" onlinecount="1" screenreccount="0" screensempty="true" issms="false" istext="true">
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div id="pics_scrollPanel">
                    <table cellspacing="0" id="pics"><input id="" name="" type="hidden" value="pics">
                        <thead></thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o iTags" id="smsCallIcon" title="message"></i></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                                <td class="spannedCell"><span class="icon-dvd-archive-restored spanTags" id="restoredCallIcon" title="restored"></span></td>
                                <td class="tableColumn"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>1</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>2013-08-06 19:08:47</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span>00:02:00</span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div>
                    <div>8882105</div>
                    <div>5010 (Caller)</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                    <div>Samsung</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="spannedCell"><span></span></td>
            <td class="spannedCell">
                <div title="20 D4 08 66 7E 82 A9 4C E1 20">20 D4 08 6...</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tableColumn"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is easy with jQuery.  Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Use [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - your code isn't minimal

Comment: no unfortunately cannot use jquery #Sam Axe. I realise its a lot of text #JonMark Perry - that is why I simplified it by collapsing the code in the editor and taking a picture. I take note of the fact that a mock up could be done via jsfiddle.

Comment: jQuery is totally unnecessary (and overkill) for this, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick snippet that got all the call_id values in your table:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('[call_id]')

var callIds = Array.prototype.map.call(rows, function(tr){
  return tr.getAttribute('call_id')
})

console.log(callIds)
```

Explanation of the code:

- `document.querySelectorAll()` queries the DOM for all elements matching a selector
- the selector I used was `[call_id]`, which gets any element with an attribute matching `call_id="<any>"`
- since the returned value of `document.querySelectorAll()` is not a normal array with a `map()` method, I use the Array's prototype to call the class method map, passing in the result as the `this` value
- `map()` returns a new Array with whatever the callback returns, in this case, the values of `call_id`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Julian - the solution works perfectly. I have just inserted my recordingTable object in place of the document reference, and then it extracts the info for me into an array. :) happy!